# In MVC5 Why is placing @Scripts.Render below @RenderBody standard in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

When I generate a MVC5 app, the `_Layout.cshtml` has the `@Scripts.Render` at the end of the file after the `@RenderBody()`.  If I add a `.js` into my `index.cshtml` that uses jquery, I get the dreaded "`$` is undefined" error.

The only way I know to fix this is to move the `@Scripts.Render` to the `<head>` section.

What is the correct approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also faced the same issue. After moving @scripts.renderto head section in layout page it is working. not sure if it is correct approach

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`@Scripts.Render` should be at the **bottom** of the page. Otherwise, you will have risks of accessing page elements which haven't been loaded at the time the scripts run.

EDIT:

If you want to include your custom scripts files, there are two ways of doing that:

**1**. In the **BundleConfig.cs**, add a new bundle for your scripts

```
 *bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/UserScripts").Include("~/Scripts/MyScripts.js"));*
```

Next, in the **_Layout.cshtml**, render the script bundle after jQuery bundle:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    @* Render the custom bundles *@
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/UserScripts")
```

**2.** Or add a new script section to your **Index.cshtml** file:

```
@section scripts {

    <script src="~/Scripts/MyScripts.js"></script>**

}
```

Comment: Right I was pretty sure that was so.  But the javascript that I put at the bottom of my index.cshtml: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bpindex.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  Since this needs to come before the jquery js file, how does this happen if the js file I'm adding is before jquery include?